# Hook Search Preprocess

Tags: search

I'm trying to manipulate search keywords before submitted for search. Using Search API and Views. Unfortunately, hook_search_preprocess funciton does not work in my custom module.

```
function mymodule_search_preprocess($text) {
    $text = str_replace("dog", "cat", $text);
return $text;
```

Cache cleared, what is wrong with it ? any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? What did you do to verify your hook is not invoked by Drupal?

Comment: I have a search view with some taxonomy selections (checkboxes). In addition, I have a BEF fulltext search filter which visitors may enter some text and search within. All I need is to alter that text before search query (for example, if text starts with some characters like \ or ' , I want to trim them.

Comment: As the said function description indicates: "This hook is called to preprocess both the text added to the search index and the keywords users have submitted for searching.", I thought that I can manipulate that fulltext input before search query. Unfortunately, my tests shows that no input text is changed that is passed to the query. I tested and observed both SQL queries by devel and SQL. I also tried hook_form_alter or some other functions but got no result. To summarize, my custom function does not change "dog" input to "cat". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A view is probably not invoking that hook, since they do all the queries by themselves.

Comment: There seems to be a bug. I filed it and found a workaround for now, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/232695/15055