# How to add custom submit logic to search_block_form?

Tags: forms, search

I want to alter the input typed into the default search block in a way that when users search for "möp" (with a German umlaut) the search should be broadened to "möp OR moep" automatically.

So I simply tried to append a custom form submit to the `search_block_form` and simply expand the string by a certain logic. But then I found out that the `search_block_form` seems to be a little bit special. In *core/modules/search/src/Form/SearchBlockForm.php* I found the following comment.

> ```
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>     // This form submits to the search page, so processing happens there.
>   }
> ```

My question now is: Where do I actually add the logic exactly if not in the form submit? I don't find any redirect or controller that would help here. Could you please point me in the right direction? Or maybe, you even have a better idea than appending the logic this way?

---

I removed the D8 tag as I guess the logic behind this is pretty equal amongst all common Drupal versions.

Comment: Submit handler is in  core/modules/search/src/Form/SearchPageForm.php.

Also Plugins with additional search parameters will need to provide their
 own form submit handler to replace this.

Comment: @sarika - I see it and can change it when I hack the code in the search module. Can you give me a rough outline on how to override this from a custom module?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in [hook_search_preprocess()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/8.3.x):

> Preprocess text for search.
>
> This hook is called to preprocess both the text added to the search
>   index and the keywords users have submitted for searching. The same
>   processing needs to be applied to both so that searches will find
>   matches.

This is not part of the preprocess in theming. This hook is called directly from the search module. Btw. German umlauts are already replaced by default.

Comment: Brilliant! Yeah, German Umlauts are already replaced by their equivalent letters without the dots. But the equivalent with the e appended to it is missing, as far as I observed it.

Comment: Hm, this function doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to do. Even the sample code on the function's page doesn't return the proposed output. Filed an issue for now https://www.drupal.org/node/2863687

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if this will help, but I found from the module documentation the following

> search_invoke_preprocess() is deprecated in drupal:9.1.0 and is removed from drupal:10.0.0. Use a custom implementation of SearchTextProcessorInterface instead. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3078162

According to which preprocessing is moved to an internal method https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3075703

I guess the last resort I found was creating a preprocess plugin as described in
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/getting-started/processors

Answer (score 0):

As [`hook_preprocess_search()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_preprocess/8.3.x) currently is not preprocessing ([issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2863687) here) I found a workaround for now. In the end I had to have the logic in two places.

First, I created a custom block that contains a custom form that roughly mimics the search block form by sending/redirecting the search string (after my desired preprocessing) to the search page. That's how my submit function looks like.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $input = $form_state->getValue('MYTEXTFIELD');

  // Trim whitespaces.
  $input = trim($input);
  $input = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $input);

  // Rewrite search string to match my logic.
  // Searching for 'Müller' rewrites to 'Müller OR Mueller'
  $processed = _rewrite_search_string($input);

  // The rest now is routine as Drupal replaces spaces with plus
  // signs between two words in a multiple word string.
  // Let's do the same.
  $keys         = explode(' ', $processed);
  $max          = sizeof($keys);
  $search_query = '';

  if ($max == 1) {
    $search_query = $keys[0];
  }

  else {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max - 1; $i++) {
      $search_query .= $keys[$i] . '+';
    }
    $search_query .= $keys[$max - 1];
  }

  // Finally, redirect to the search page with the expected
  // query pattern. For example 'Müller+OR+Mueller'.
  $url = Url::fromUserInput('/search/content?keys=' .
    $search_query);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);

}
```

Second, the same logic but in a different way needed to get appended to the real `'search_form'` on the search page. So I added a custom submit function that looks the same as the original search form submit function except for the little addition that adds the desired logic.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {

    $form['#submit'][] = 'MYCUSTOMSUBMIT';
  }
}

function MYCUSTOMSUBMIT(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $input = $form_state->getValue('keys');

  // Here the same as above. 'Müller' gets rewritten to 'Müller OR Mueller'.
  $processed = _rewrite_search_string($input);

  $query['keys'] = $processed;

  // Rest is just c/p.
  $route = 'search.view_' . $form_state->get('search_page_id');
  $form_state->setRedirect(
    $route,
    [],
    ['query' => $query]
  );
}
```

---

As soon as `hook_search_preprocess()` gets fixed I mark @4k4's answer as the correct one.